# How to Expire Link after 10 min

Tags: php, time

I want to Simply expire link after 10 min in PHP.Assuming I have create custom email send template.So in email i have added one link.So how to expire email link after 10 min.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/generate-one-time-download-link-with-expiration-php/

Comment: please explain the complete scenario ? Is 10 min considered from first hit ?

Comment: Hello @AbdulPathan i have update my question. Please check

Comment: Assuming you are creating a link dynamically, you can store the link & its expiry time in database, on the page you can validate if time has expired or not to show the page. Does this works for you ?

Comment: i have email send using controller.so not use database @AbdulPathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer.All Suggestions.

My Controller File **`CustomerDelete.php`**. And

1. I have get current time **`$current_time = time('h:i:s');`**
2. In Email Template set time like :-

   ```
   ->setTemplateVars([
      "name" =>$customerName,
      "id" => $encodeId,
      "time" => $current_time
   ])
   ```
3. In Email Template my **`account_expire.html`** file set time with URL :- **`[_query:['id':$id,'exp':$time]]`**
4. Final Work expire link operation in my controller **`CustomerSuccess.php`**:-

   ```
   <?php
       $exp = $this->getRequest()->getParam('exp');
       $currenttime = time('h:i:s');
       $expiretime = $exp;
    if ($currenttime - $expiretime < 10*60) 
    {
      echo "Link Is Not Expire";
    }else{
      echo "Link is Expire";
    }
   ```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: It allows customers to modify the exp date.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a link with param attached to it. This param can be a timestamp or token.

**1. Approach with timestamp**

Your page link in email would be something like

```
<a href="https://your-site/your-page?expires=1600881883">Click here</a>
```

On your page, you can get the expire timestamp from URL, generate timestamp of current time & compare if 10 min has passed. Show the page if 10 min hasn't passed else do not show it.

*Drawback : geek could manipulate the timestamp to have access of expired page as well.*

**2. Approach with token**

- Create a token and maintain it in a separate database table.(eg: Token, page_link, expiry_timestamp).
- Pass this token with the email like

> ```
> <a href="https://your-site/your-page?token={token_string}">Click here</a>
> ```

- On your page, you can get the token from URL, search this token in your table, compare if 10 min has passed. Show the page if 10 min hasn't passed else do not show it.
- This option would be more secure than first approach.

Hope it was helpful.

Thanks

Comment: my already URl look like email link :- xyz.com/router/controller/action/?id=QWEQ12321 @Abdul Pathan

Comment: Could you explain what is the `id` attribute ? and how you have used it in your code? what exactly it does ?

Answer (score 1):

Unorthodox solution just for fun :) You mentioned that you're sending inside controller:

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Token;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Send extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var FrontendInterface
     */
    private $cache;

    public function __construct(
        FrontendInterface $cache,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->cache = $cache;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // random_bytes is available at PHP 7
        $token = base64_encode(random_bytes(32));
        $this->cache->save(
            "this is a valid link :)", // value doesn't matter
            "my-token-$token", // key
            ['expiration-token'], // tags
            10*60 // expiration in seconds
        );

        $link = $this->_url->getUrl('myroute/token/verify', ['_query' => ['id' => $token]]);
        // send email with this link to xyz.com/router/controller/action/?id=QWEQ12321

        /** @var Raw $result */
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
        $result->setContents("<a href='$link' target='_blank'>$token</a>");
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Verify controller:

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Token;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Verify extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var FrontendInterface
     */
    private $cache;

    public function __construct(
        FrontendInterface $cache,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->cache = $cache;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var Raw $result */
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);

        $token = $this->_request->getParam('id');
        $isValid = $this->cache->load("my-token-$token");
        if (false === $isValid) {
            $result->setContents('This link does not have power here .');
            return $result;
        }

        // verified, put your code here
        $result->setContents('Valid !');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

app/etc/frontend/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Token\Send">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="cache" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Token\Verify">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="cache" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Hello @Roman my already URL this :- xyz.com/router/controller/action/?id=QWEQ12321

Comment: @MohitPatel, in your send controller import cache interface and use my first snippet to generate `id` parameter.     In your verify controller, import `cache` again, and you already have `$this->request`, use my second snippet to verify `$this->request->getParam('id')`

Comment: Hello @Roman explain more i don't understand .Is that possible you update answer   More explanation?

Comment: Hi @MohitPatel, I updated the answer to include controller example. random_bytes is available for PHP 7

Comment: Okay i will try and  update you . Thanks you.

Comment: Showing this error :- https://prnt.sc/umuvuh

Comment: Changed cache interface to \Magento\Framework\Config\CacheInterface

Comment: @MohitPatel, finally had time to test my code, sorry. Added missing configuration preference in di.xml, updated full answer. Of course, normally generate and verify logic should be moved to a separate class to be called from controllers.

Comment: pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328962/85907

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving data in the database than save current time and then compare that time and date.

if you are not saving it then pass date and time in parameters and compare it with current time date.

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a solution using cache lifetime (10 minutes), save your token_key into cache service with 10 minutes is cache lifetime, if you can't get your token_key on the cache system, that means the token_key is expired.